# cmake rule that depends on the output of a command

Tags: cmake

How do I generate source files during the pre-build step if and only if they need to be regenerated?

One of my project's dependencies is a library (`libfoo`) which expensive to relink (several minutes) and even more expensive to rebuild (less than an hour). Generating the source files for this dependency is inexpensive (several seconds), but using out-of-date sources would render the resultant application suite useless. I have a command `check_foo.sh` that will exit with a non-zero status when the sources must be regenerated, but I haven't been able to determine how to convince CMake to run `check_foo.sh` during every build and only rebuild `libfoo` when `check_foo.sh` returns nonzero.

In trying to create a simple proof, the closest I have gotten is as follows, although only ever runs `generate_foo_if.sh` once. The ultimate goal is that `generate_foo_if.sh` gets run unconditionally, but `libfoo` is only rebuilt when `generate_foo_if.sh` modifies `foo.cpp`.

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8 FATAL_ERROR)
project(my_project
        VERSION 1.0.0.0
        LANGUAGES CXX)
add_custom_command(OUTPUT foo.cpp
                   COMMAND "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/generate_foo_if.sh" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/foo.cpp" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/check_foo.sh"
                   WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
                   COMMENT "Generating foo.cpp..."
                  )
add_library(foo STATIC foo.cpp)
add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main foo)
```

main.cpp

```
#include "foo.hpp"
int main(int,char**){
    return foo::exit_status;
}
```

foo.hpp

```
#pragma once
namespace foo {
extern const int exit_status;
}
```

check_foo.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
exit $(((${RANDOM} % 2 )))
```

generate_foo_if.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
CHECK=${2:-./check_foo.sh}
if [ ${CHECK} -eq 0 ]; then
    exit 0
fi
msg=$(cat <<__EOF
#include "foo.hpp"
namespace foo {
const int exit_status = 1;
}
__EOF
)
echo "${msg}" >${1:-foo.cpp}
```

Comment: I should also note that adding a bogus `OUTPUT` to the `add_custom_command` results in `libfoo` being regenerated with every invocation of `make`, which is undesirable from a time perspective, even though it ensures the correct `libfoo` is always used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, I wasn't very far off the mark.

The critical difference seems to be in creating a custom target rather than a custom command, using `BYPRODUCTS` rather than `OUTPUT`, and explicitly adding the dependency. Updated CMakeLists.txt is below, and results in the desired behavior (i.e. `libfoo` is only regenerated if it should be).

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8 FATAL_ERROR)
project(my_project
    VERSION 1.0.0.0
    LANGUAGES CXX)
add_custom_target(generate_foo
              COMMAND "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/generate_foo_if.sh"  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/foo.cpp" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/check_foo.sh"
              WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
              BYPRODUCTS foo.cpp
             )
add_library(foo STATIC foo.cpp)
add_dependencies(foo generate_foo)
include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main foo)
```

While I can't really say I know *why* it works, this does what I want.